# How can I use the "dplyr" chain operator %>% get the left side itself in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

package "dplyr" has a chain operator. But I have a problem with how to get the right side term itself.

For example:

```
c(5,7,8,1) %>% sum(`[`(1:3)) # get result 27 (This is wrong)

c(5,7,8,1) %>% sum(.[1:3]) # get result 41 (This is also wrong)

c(5,7,8,1) %>% `[`(1:3) %>% sum()   # get result 20 (This is right)
```

Why the first line and second line codes are wrong? What has happened in them?

Comment: I think in the second case , we are summing the `c(5,7,8,1) %>%  c(.[1:3])`

Comment: @akrun `c(5,7,8,1) %>% c(.[1:3])` will give `5 7 8 1 5 7 8`, but  c(5,7,8,1) %>% .[1:3] will give `5 7 8 1`. Why this happen?

Comment: Because `%>%`give the lhs as the first parameter to the function, the extracted part is given as second

Comment: @akrun c(5,7,8,1) %>% c(`[`(1:3)) will give `5 7 8 1 1 2 3` back, but `c(5,7,8,1) %>% `[`(1:3)` give back `5 7 8`. I have no idea...Why this happens

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dot `.` is correct. However, `%>%` also inserts it as the first argument:

```
x = c(5,7,8,1)
x %>% sum(.[1 : 3])
```

Is the same as:

```
sum(x, x[1 : 3])
```

You can explicitly prevent this behaviour by wrapping the expression in braces:

```
x %>% {sum(.[1 : 3])}
```

However, at this point it may be better to split the pipeline up a bit more (as you’ve done yourself):

```
x %>% `[`(1 : 3) %>% sum()
```

Or, using magrittr helper functions (requires `library(magrittr)`):

```
x %>% extract(1 : 3) %>% sum()
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's quote the doc:

> Placing lhs as the first argument in rhs call The default behavior of
>   %>% when multiple arguments are required in the rhs call, is to place
>   lhs as the first argument, i.e. x %>% f(y) is equivalent to f(x, y).

So what happens ?

When you call sum, it is called like this:

```
n <- c(5,7,8,1) 
sum(n,n[1:3])
```

The lhs of `%>%` is passed as first arg to sum, and the subset as second arg. 
On your third form, only the ouput of the selector is passed as argument to sum